# Convolution Neural Network Data Augmentation After Normalization Works Much Better

Tags: neural-networks, normalization, conv-neural-network, data-augmentation

I am training a Convolution Neural Network similar to LeNet5 to detect road signs in the German Traffic Signs Dataset. With about 35,000 training samples I get to 95% validation accuracy. To improve accuracy, I tried augmenting the training set with random Affine transformations of original images.

When I perform augmentation and then normalize my data (mean subtraction and division by standard deviation), the network converges very slowly and validation accuracy actually goes down. However when I perform augmentation after normalization the same network converges much faster and the validation error improves to 97%.

Is there a theoretical basis for this? To me it makes more sense to perform augmentation before normalization because un-normalized images look much better and I can tell if augmentation is working correctly by plotting those images.

Comment: Exactly!! Augmentation is always done before. I am surprised by the behavior of your network. Can you post both the architectures ?

Comment: What is the validation procedure? Is it a separate chunk? Do you split and cross-validate?

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, in the case of normalizing after augmentation, if you are normalizing your images by subtracting off the mean and dividing by the variance of the pixels, for operations like Brightness and/or Contrast changes in the images, most likely these augmentation operations are not having effect because the normalization zeros the mean and makes the stddev unit.

For the second case, yes, it is strange.

Hope I could help.